# How do I insert highlight or code-block into Sphinx-style docstrings?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

For example:

```
def foo():
    '''
    .. highlight:: python
    import sys
    '''
```

Doesn't produce desired output (it prints the word "highlight" verbatim and doesn't format the following code in any special way).  Same happens for `code-block`.

I tried different indentation etc.  No matter what, generator succeeds with roughly the same, but not the desired output.

Comment: You are missing indentation; try adding 4 spaces before the import line

Comment: @Vinny apparently, I also need an empty line between the two!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Comparing your code with the [docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html),  you are missing indentation and an empty line between the highlight and the actual code. It should be like this:

```
def foo():
    '''
    .. highlight:: python
    .. code-block:: python

        import sys
        ...
    '''
```

Comment: That is not enough. The code must be in a literal block (a block where the preceding paragraph ends with `::`).

Comment: What you have after the edit does work but is redundant. `.. highlight:: python` can be removed.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956831/1497139 for a much better explanation